# link to dynamic anchors

Tags: javascript, anchor, deep-linking, dynamic-content

I have a json array of instructor data that feeds into a template and generates a "card" for each instructor. Each instructor contains a named anchor and I want to be able to link to the various generated anchors from an external page. i.e. `instructors.htm#MrsTaylorGreen`

It seems that by the time the cards have a chance to generate, all the browser's jump-to-anchor behavior is done.

I'm considering this bit of jQuery derived from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

```
// page load, draw instructor cards then...
// scroll to the named anchor if there is one
var anchor = document.location.href.split("#")[1];
if($("#" + anchor).length)
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + anchor).offset().top
    }, 2000);
```

Is this necessary? Or is there a more efficient alternative to link to dynamic anchors?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, but if you do `window.location.href` = "#anchor-here"` the page will jump to the `id="anchor-here"` element

Comment: serious brain fart. I tried setting the href before I asked the question but whatever I was doing before was causing it to re-re-re-fresh... >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead, to get the hash (for your anchor):

```
var anchor = window.location.hash;
```

and then:

```
if ($(anchor).length > 0)
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(anchor).offset().top
}, 2000);
```

The way you get the hash `document.location.href.split("#")[1];` can (and will) produce errors if there is no hash in the URL; because the array (from the split) will have only one element in that case.

Comment: stupid me... of course. I remember something I was writing throwing an "index out of bounds" error, however I wasn't getting that in any of my current browsers (Opera, Webkit, and Mozilla) so I figured it must have been PHP or something and just moved on. And how silly that I forgot about all the other parsings (that are usually not what I need) I think I need to relax my mind and get away from this machine. Anyway +1 For the pro-tip, thank you!